# Trying to find entries in my MongoDB by the find(), but just getting [object Object] returned

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Im trying to access my mongoDB and find all entries that are held in there, under 'player' names. If the player name entered is already in the DB, then simply show 'use another name'. However I'm getting back [object OBJECT] and the Chrome console shows no errors. Please can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using the find()

**server.js**

```
// This is for getting the list of all players from my DB
app.get("/getPlayers", function(request, response) {
    db.getPlayers().then(function(players){
        console.log(players);
        response.send(players);
    });
});
```

**db.js**

```
async function getPlayers(){
    return await schemas.Player.find();
}
```

**script.js**

```
// This will only appear if a player has won the game, it will ask to enter their name
async function enterName() {
    var personName = prompt("Please enter your name", "...");

    // search database for the players name that's just been entered
    //var players = getPlayers();

    $.get("http://localhost:9000/getPlayers", function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        alert(data);

        // loop through each player (data)
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            // if the name is equal to person name, output.
            if (value.name == personName)
            {
                alert("match found");

            }
        });
    });
}
```

[image: Local Host returns this message]

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify(players)`

Comment: Hello, in the server.js file?

Comment: But the OP gets that in the UI and not in the API @manikantgautam

Comment: @K.Haydock check my answer

Comment: `[object Object]` is just the result of the implicit call of `data.toString()` in `alert(data)`. `console.log(data)` should give you an improved output (at least when you use any browser but IE) where you can see all objects and their properties.

Comment: That output means the objects get cast to Strings; you can easily reproduce this with `alert({});`. What I'd do is append `personName` as parameter to the URL, then try and find a player by that name in the DB. If the result is empty, the name is free. That way you don't have to send back all players to the client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` you get in the AJAX response through the API is a array of objects so you need to stringify that in your alert like `alert(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: I'm not quite sure why `JSON.stringify()` should be the answer to a, imho, non-existing problem. The output is just the result of using `alert()` instead of `console.log()` (and maybe the choice of a terrible browser like IE).

Comment: Thank you Ankita, that's worked perfectly for me :)

Comment: @K.Haydock glad to help :)